# Display bug: word at end of line is not displayed

Tags: bug, status-norepro

In the 2012-02-26 19:48 revision of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242) the word "only" is erroneously not displayed at the end of the first line in the case $\rm\:n > 1$, in IE 8.9.7601.17514, see screen grab below.
[image]

Comment: Shows up on Firefox 9.0.1.

Comment: No issue with Chrome 17.0.963.56 either.

Comment: Also OK in Safari 5.1.2.  Safari has its own display bugs related to MathJax here, though.

Comment: FYI, I'm going to rollback to your stated revision for a minute to test in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

After rolling back to the 2012-02-26 19:48 revision, I opened your answer in IE8 from a Windows XP virtual machine, but I couldn't see the missing "only":

[image]

On my main machine, I tested the IE7 and IE8 compatibility modes, as well, but couldn't see anything amiss.

The only thing I can think of is one of the "Related" questions' titles contained LaTeX that interfered with rendering.

Please let me know if you see this behavior again.

Comment: Yes, the bug must depend on some other state on the page since I too can no longer reproduce it with the current version of the page. That seems to often be the case with these sort of bugs (I reported a few in the past). We need some way to snapshot the state of the page when the bug is triggered.

Comment: I agree - perhaps a screenshot of the entire page when it occurs?  That would help most, so we can attempt to recreate the display.